# Why doesn't this \xpathcmd work inside expl3 scope?

Tags: expl3, patching

Consider the following example, the same `\xpatchcmd` works outside `ExplSyntax`, but doesn't work inside. Why is this happening?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{regexpatch}

\begin{document}

\def\foo{foo}
\def\bar{with a macro \foo}

\bar

\ExplSyntaxOn

\xpatchcmd{\bar}{\foo}{bar}{}{\FAIL}

\ExplSyntaxOff

% \xpatchcmd{\bar}{\foo}{bar}{}{\FAIL}

\bar

\end{document}
```

Comment: you have spaces in the \bar command and they have a different catcode in expl3.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But why would the space in `\bar` matters? The patched part `{\foo}` doesn't contain any space so I thought it should be able to get matched.

Comment: patching has to reassemble the definition after the patch and that fails if the catcode regime is not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeX provides only two ways of accessing the replacement text of a macro: either by expanding it or by using `\meaning`.

In some cases a patch can be made with the first method, but it's not a really general possibility.

The method used by `etoolbox`/`xpatch` and `regexpatch` exploits `\meaning`. The problem with `\meaning` is that the replacement text is delivered as a “string”: all characters of category code 12 (including the backslash) except for spaces that retain category code 10.

A successful patch needs a few steps:

1. the obtained string is passed through `\scantokens` in order to see whether reconstruction is possible;
2. the reconstructed token list is compared with the original;
3. the “find” token list is looked for in the reconstructed token list;
4. if it is found, it is replaced.

Failure of the second step will result in the patch not being applied. You must remember that `\scantokens` (or its `expl3` wrapper) uses the category code regime current at the moment it is applied; in the scope of `\ExplSyntaxOn`, spaces have category code 9 and you don't want to reconstruct a macro ignoring spaces in the original one.

This is the reason why your `\bar` is not patchable inside the scope of `\ExplSyntaxOn`.

A possible improvement of `regexpatch` could be using category code tables, but it's major work. But the main idea is that extensive patching is bad.